# MailSender spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to run simple mailsender service:

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public void sendMessage(SaveSurveyDTO saveSurvey) {

        title += "title2";
        templateMessage.setSubject(title);
        // templateMessage.setTo(email.toString());
        templateMessage.setTo("my@mail.com");
        mailSender.send(templateMessage);
    }

}


@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "adres");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "NTLM");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain", "DOMAIN");
        sender.setHost("host");
        sender.setPort(25);
        sender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
        sender.setUsername("username");
        sender.setPassword("pass");
        return sender;

    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run this, I recieve the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testappController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.test.service.MailService org.test.testappController.mailService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage org.test.service.MailService.templateMessage; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at org.test.testapp.main(testapp.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.test.service.MailService org.test.testappController.mailService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage org.test.service.MailService.templateMessage; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage org.test.service.MailService.templateMessage; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage org.test.service.MailService.templateMessage; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is telling you what is wrong:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The main issue is the fact you are having field in your service of the type `SimpleMailMessage` which you have annotated with `@Autowired`. However there is no such bean in your `@Configuration` class.

Either add that bean definition to your configuration (which I wouldn't recommend) or simply create the `SimpleMailMessage` inside your method.

```
public void sendMessage(SaveSurveyDTO saveSurvey) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();    
    title += "title2";
    message.setSubject(title);
    // templateMessage.setTo(email.toString());
    message.setTo("my@mail.com");
    mailSender.send(message);
}
```

**Pro Tip**

You are using Spring Boot then use it... Remove your`@Configuration` class and just put the configuration in `application.properties`. Spring Boot already [has mail support](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-email) (as of Spring Boot 1.2 that is!).

```
spring.mail.host=adres
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms=NTLM
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain=DOMAIN
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
```

Comment: pro tip- now i have to remove @autowired annotations from mailsender?

Comment: Looks like it wont, it cause same error as above but for mailSender.

Comment: As mentioned it works for Spring Boot 1.2 or up, which version are you using?

Comment: i'm using 1.2.5 version

Comment: Then you should get a mail sender, did you include the `spring-boot-starter-mail`?

Comment: Are you actually using spring boot to start your application? Please add your starter class and pom to your question.

Comment: Hi! I'm using the same implementation as your Pro Tip, but the problem is that the bean is not inject in the tests. If i run the project work normally, but in the test it fail with this message: "Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender".
Do you know what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm sure you figured it out, but you should add @ImportAutoConfiguration(MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class) to your test class. The SpringRunner does not do all the fancy Auto Configuration that the Application/@EnableAutoConfiguration does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are getting is that Spring cannot inject an instance of `SimpleMailMessage`:

```
@Autowired
private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;
```

This is completely normal and you should not construct a [`SimpleMailMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html) this way, it is not a Spring Bean. Rather, use the default constructor:

```
SimpleMailMessage templateMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
```

and set the properties [`from`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html#setFrom-java.lang.String-), [`to`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html#setTo-java.lang.String-), etc. according to your needs.

Answer (score -5):

Please add the Qualifier like this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mailSender")
private MailSender mailSender;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since the problem is about SimpleMailMessage not getting injected.